# Absolute select 1st empty cell in column A of table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that i keep track of withdrawals and payments to my creditors. I've gotten it to copy the info needed from 1 sheet to the table.
However, I am not able to get it to find the absolute last empty cell in column A of the table.
here is the code:
'''

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim MEx As Worksheet, ExT As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Set MEx = Sheets("Monthly Expenses")
Set ExT = Sheets("Tracking")
ExT.Activate
lr = ExT.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ExT.Range("A" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("B2").Value 'Date
ExT.Range("B" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("N5").Value 'Deposit
ExT.Range("C" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("H15").Value 'ATM Fees
ExT.Range("D" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("H14").Value 'Withdrawn
ExT.Range("E" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("P4").Value 'Exchange Rate
ExT.Range("F" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("Q4").Value 'Actual Rate
ExT.Range("G" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("D23").Value 'Exchanged To Solis
ExT.Range("H" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("N19").Value 'UMB-Balance
ExT.Range("I" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("N23").Value 'PayPal
ExT.Range("J" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("P23").Value 'PayPal Balance
ExT.Range("K" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("N22").Value 'Capital One
ExT.Range("L" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("P22").Value 'Capital One Balance
ExT.Range("M" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("N24").Value 'Avant Loan
ExT.Range("N" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("P24").Value 'Avant Loan Balance
ExT.Range("O" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("N25").Value 'American Express
ExT.Range("P" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("P25").Value 'American Express Balance
ExT.Range("Q" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("N26").Value 'Petal
ExT.Range("R" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("P26").Value 'Petal Balance
ExT.Range("S" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("N27").Value 'MileStone
ExT.Range("T" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("P27").Value 'MileStone Balance
ExT.Range("U" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("N28").Value 'Premier
ExT.Range("V" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("P28").Value 'Premier Balance
ExT.Range("W" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("N29").Value 'Scott
ExT.Range("X" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("P29").Value 'Scott Balance
ExT.Range("Y" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("N30").Value 'Blank
ExT.Range("Z" & lr).Value = MEx.Range("P30").Value 'Blank Balance
```

''''

Sometimes I make entries manually, I put the date in Column A, and then fill in the appropriate info in the other columns. If they don't have an entry, i leave them blank.

I had several rows with the date, but very little in the other columns of 3 entries. Today I used the command button and it filled in a row above several that were not full. Thus the need to have this formula look specifically for the first empty cell in column A.

Any fix for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `lr = ExT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1`. You were looking in column B (`2)`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know much about Excel and generally google for the formula for what I need it to do. That's where I got the first part of this code. I figured out the rest of it, because what I found, had 1 line of copying to 3 cells.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you are trying to do?